# How to get the Currency formatter with decimal and grouping separator in swift using ISOCode

Tags: swift, currency-formatting

Decimal and Grouping separator are not correct:

```
func setAmountString (amountValue: Int, isoCodeStr: String) {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = isoCodeStr
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currencyISOCode

     if let formatterStr: String = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amountValue))  {
      return formatterStr
    }else {
      return "0.0"
    }
}
```

print("amount in USD (setAmountString(amountValue: Int(1234567.89), isoCodeStr: "USD"))")
    print("amount in GBP (setAmountString(amountValue: Int(1234567.89), isoCodeStr: "GBP"))")
    print("amount in EUR (setAmountString(amountValue: Int(1234567.89), isoCodeStr: "EUR"))")

```
Output:
amount in USD Optional("$1,234,567.00")
amount in GBP Optional("£1,234,567.00")
amount in EUR Optional("€1,234,567.00") 

Expected Output:
amount in USD Optional("$1,234,567.89")
amount in GBP Optional("£1.234.567,89")
amount in EUR Optional("€1.234.567,89")
```

Comment: I am unable to understand, Please explain

Comment: First, GB actually uses `.` as the decimal separator, as does the US, so that's a mistaken expectation (see this page https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html among others.  Second, it doesn't seem like setting the currency does (nor would I expect it to) change the separators, as I would expect that to use local conventions.  See also `NumberFormatter.locale` for changing the actual number formatting.

Comment: I don't want to represent the currency based on user Locale. I want the currency format based on ISOCurrencyCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the way you cast your value to Int:

`Int(1234567.89)`

This rounds your floating-point value to `1234567` even before passing it to `setAmountString`.

Try casting it to `Float` instead, or not casting it at all. You also need to change your function signature from

`func setAmountString (amountValue: Int, isoCodeStr: String)`

to

`func setAmountString (amountValue: Float, isoCodeStr: String)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `locale` to change the number format (separators, etc.)  Use `currencyCode` to change the currency symbol.  E.g.:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currencyAccounting
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "DE")
formatter.currencyCode = "eur"
let string = formatter.string(from: 1234567) // "1.234.567,00 €"
```

Comment: I don't have the locale. Is there any way to get the locale using CurrencyISOCode.

Comment: Not really, the two aren’t related.  Somebody in Germany would expect to see 1.234,56 $, where somebody in the US would expect to see $1,234.56.  The currency code represents what currency in use, while the locale defines how they want numbers formatted.

Comment: My recommendation would be to leave the locale as is, as it will default to the correct value for the user.